# How to automate login using Android Studio Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio

### About me

I am a quite a starter but I have worked with Android Studio before; creating simple data scraping apps and more. Bu I was bashed on here once for just asking for answers without trying, that is why I am giving much as effort to make clean as possible. I am not looking for just answers, I was hoping to learn something building this app. Sorry for my terrible English and also thanks in advance!

---

### Infinite Campus

If you haven't heard of [Infinite Campus](https://cvsdpa.infinitecampus.org/campus/chartiersvalley.jsp), it is a grading website which students and teachers use. The website is generally great; it gives a lots of informations and it is clean. Besides the website, they also have an app. But the app is terrible. Reason is:

1. It is Slow: refreshing the data takes too much time.
2. Less information: for some reason it has less information; like GPA and more.
3. On Android it just looks terrible
   And I decided to create my own app, and hoping to learn new things in the process.

---

### My App

I want my personal App same as [Infinite Campus App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.infinitecampus.mobilePortal&hl=en).
The app is fairly simple, it is only does two things:

1. Log in
2. Scrape Data and Display.

The site is: [Here](https://cvsdpa.infinitecampus.org/campus/scripts/login.js)

---

### Problem/Question

I do not know where to start.

- Do you guys have any good tutorials?
- What do I need to learn?
- Is the site good for such a thing?

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can create an Application like that but first, you need to understand your requirements and what are the **technologies** you are going to use like.

**1**.) In your Campus App you want to enable the *login* functionality for that you must have some database where you can store the user information like *email* and *password* for this **Firebase** comes handy with [Real-time Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/).

**2**.) you want to store the student's score or test mark for this Again you need to design a database where you can store it so Real-time database from firebase again helps in easy to use integrate.

**3**.) Next process involves making the UI in android which can be referenced in java where you can implement your business logic.

Useful links you may want to get started

[firebase login](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/auth/README.md)

[realtime database](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/database/README.md)

[Using recyclerview for list type things](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-the-RecyclerView)

[for displaying drawer menus](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)

Comment: First of all, thank that was fast, but can't you store it in the phone, like the grade and such?

Comment: yes you can for that you need SQLITE it allows you to enable the offline functionality in your app.
here you go
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite.html